# Codeigniter - Add a product with the same ID if options are different

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I'm currently building a simple ecommerce site and have ran into an interesting problem.

Basically, the products are in the products table however there are also a number of other options such as price, colour etc... some of these have an effect on the total price.

However, if the same product but with a different set of options exist then the product id is obviously the same and the item is not added into the codeigniter cart.

The easiest way that I have thought of is to allow products with the same id to be included in the cart, is this easily possible? Is there a better way of tackling this problem?

Any ideas will be very helpful!

Comment: there is no 'codeigniter cart" as codeigniter is a framework,so your working with something that uses codeigniter, what is it?

Comment: @Dagon: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html

Comment: OK well here is an update, it appears to be due to the fact that i'm using multidimensional arrays as the options and the hash is appearing to be the same due to the fact that the arrays are just showing up as 'Array'... so i need to rewrite that hash.

Comment: My thoughts: The CI shopping cart class is a toy (or starting point, if you choose to see it that way) and as-is, not robust enough for anything serious. After some quick testing it looks like there isn't a straight-forward way to do what you want. +1 and wish you luck.

Comment: people use that, i though it was just a demo.

Comment: @Dagon Yeah they do, although it is rather simple. But that's all I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so I found an answer to my problem which people may find helpful.

Basically I was using multidimensional arrays for the options which is not supported by Codeigniter's cart class.

This was then generating the same row id due to the fact that the arrays were showing up as array but may also have been breaking the implode function used to generate the hash in the Codeigniter Cart class.

To fix this you can simple replace this line within the CI_Cart class:

```
$rowid = md5($items['id'].implode('', $items['options']));
```

with this line:

```
$rowid = md5($items['id'].serialize($items['options']));
```

to fix the problem.

This then creates a storable representation of the multidimensional array as text that is then hashed and will always be unique if there is a multidimensional array used as the options value.